# OSX freezing for 1-2 minutes, can't find anything in logs

Tags: macos, freeze, macos-sierra

I'm just looking for advice on how to debug this as it's really annoying.  My computer will regularly (once/day on average) lock up for a minute or two.  I can move the mouse around but literally nothing else works.  Apps stop responding, keyboard stops working, nothing.  The mouse even gets stuck in zoomed in "find me" mode sometimes.  If I leave it alone I eventually get a beachball and a while longer it all starts working again.  I've looked through console logs but don't see anything obvious.

Comment: How old is your Mac? A lot of computer (mac / pc) when they have hdd that is on its way out has that symptoms (general sluggishness or non-responsiveness) - this is due to the OS trying to read data from the HDD that may be requiring longer-than-normal time to read (and maybe repeated attempt to read and doing ECC while reading) and that slows things down.

Comment: 6 months, it's a MBP Retina w/ touchbar.  Also note that this isn't the first computer I've seen exhibit these symptoms.  My last work computer did the same thing albeit less frequently.  I can't find anyone complaining about it online though :(

Comment: That is making it hard to narrow it down. Did it happen with a clean install? Maybe you installed a software that may be using up lots of resources? Check activity monitor and maybe you can spot anything that used up lots of either CPU or lots of HDD activity?

Comment: I can't check activity monitor, that's the problem.  Even if I had it open I couldn't switch to it and it wouldn't update.  I'm pretty sure it's some rogue root-level service since it's happened on multiple machines and everything is inoperable (no user-level software has resources to lock the machine like this).  Console logs are the only thing I can think of to go on since it's so sporadic and the machine is unusable when it happens, but that came up empty.  I'm hoping someone has some clever idea, maybe keep a running log of *something* then look at it right after the issue occurs again.